# Aparecer recaptcha após 3 tentativas erradas

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

implementei o recaptcha no site, porém está muito oneroso aos usuários cada vez que forem logar ficar clicando nas imagens, queria que o mesmo aparecesse após 3 tentativas, mas não estou conseguindo, quero fazer via JS...

Comment: Poste seu código por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara é bem facinho, você pode usar uma váriavel global como no meu exemplo:

```js
tentativas = 0;
//defino uma função ao clickar no botao
document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", logar);

function logar() {
    var login = document.getElementById("inpLogin").value;
    var senha = document.getElementById("inpSenha").value;
    
    tentativas += 1;
    //aqui sua tratativa para logar o usuario
    if(login=='admin' && senha=='admin'){
     alert('logado');
    }else{
     alert('usuario e senha incorreto, numero de tentativas: '+tentativas);
    }
    
    if(tentativas==3){
     document.getElementById("recaptcha").style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <body>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" id='inpLogin' size='10' placeholder='login'>
      <input type="password" id='inpSenha'  size='10' placeholder='senha'>
      <button id="enviar" type='button'>LOGAR</button>
    </form>  
    <br>
    <div id='recaptcha' style='display: none;'>
      <img src="https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/images/newCaptchaAnchor.gif" alt="" width='270'>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

e ai você deixa a `div` com o **recaptcha** com o `style display = none` (ou seja escondida), e ai você mostra ela quando o numero de tentativas for maior que 3.

Comment: Poxa cara muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda em !!